# incorrect syntax for multiple statement inside if

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, syntax-error

I tried to modify my batch code to catch more cases. I have a line that checks input, and I wanted to have a specific initialization for a specific input

*This is the input call:*

```
:: get user input
set /p ph="Enter phase (e.g: 7, 8, 81, 82, 9, vs2, vs3): "
```

*This is the initialization:*

```
::(loc2, loc3, synergy are all variables I use in different places)
    if %ph%==vs2(
        set loc2=C:\mp_4m_ph2
        set loc3=C:\mp_4m_ph2\mp_4m
        set synergy=C:\synergy\mp4m_ph2
        )
```

*Result:*

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I don't understand what's going wrong here, since I used if before: `if %wantbackup%==n (goto start_delete)` and that worked fine

If I remove this `if` entirely there are no errors.
I also verified this is the location of the problem by `echo 1` just before the `if` and inside it. Only the *before* part printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Using if like this `if %ph%==vs2(` is illegal. A white space must appear before the bracket, like this: `if %ph%==vs2 (`